# Tooltip text is wrong for favorite question icon

Tags: bug, bookmarks, tooltips

While browsing the questions, I noticed that if some question is marked as favorite by someone, favorite question marking icon is displaying wrong tooltip text for me:

> This is a favorite question (click again to undo)

While I didn't marked it as favorite.

Comment: It shows the tootip even no one has favorited the question. (e.g. test on this question)

Comment: point here is (click again to undo) should show only if it is already clicked.

Comment: Where did I say that's not a point?

Comment: @hims056 : comment is not for you. its for those not getting the point in question.